# Python nested generators mock infinite data

Tags: python

So I've got something along the lines of the following

```py
def _data_yielder(v, iter_to):
    for i in range(iter_to):
        bla = yield (v, i)
        print(f"Result received from send: {bla}")

def _get_data():
    """
    generator that iterates some expensive-to-open files
    """
    for i, v in enumerate(["A", "B", "C"]):
        offset = i + 2
        print(f"{v} should go up to {(v, offset-1)}")
        yield next(_data_yielder(v, offset))
        
def _reset():
    resetted_generator = _get_data()
    initial_value = next(resetted_generator)
    return initial_value, resetted_generator

count = 0
iter_data, data_generator_process = _reset()
print(f"\toutput value: {iter_data}")   
while True:
    try:
        iter_data = data_generator_process.send(f"test_{count}")
        count += 1
        print(f"\toutput value: {iter_data}")
    except StopIteration as e:
        print(e)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I'm seeing

```
A should go up to ('A', 1)
    output value: ('A', 0)
B should go up to ('B', 2)
    output value: ('B', 0)
C should go up to ('C', 3)
    output value: ('C', 0)
```

but I expect to see

```
A should go up to ('A', 1)
    output value: ('A', 0)
    output value: ('A', 1)
B should go up to ('B', 2)
    output value: ('B', 0)
    output value: ('B', 1)
    output value: ('B', 2)
C should go up to ('C', 3)
    output value: ('C', 0)
    output value: ('C', 1)
    output value: ('C', 2)
    output value: ('C', 3)
```

I'm not really sure what the error is (clearly). `_reset` is to be called whenever I want to reset the entire sequence. As far as I can tell, `_reset` returns a generator to me. That generator (from _get_data) is itself a generator over `_data_yielder`). In my head, once the `_data_yielder` has hit the `StopIterationError`, control should go back to `_get_data` which should then move to the next alphabet. Also, the `send` value is not being printed, but it's not throwing an error or the error isn't kicking up?

Comment: There is only a single ``next`` call of each letter's ``_data_yielder``. Why do you expect to see the other results of each ``_data_yielder``?

Comment: "That generator (from _get_data) is itself a generator over ``_data_yielder``" it's not, it's an iterator over ``next(_data_yielder(v, offset))`` – individual pairs of ``(<letter>, 0)`` – which also conveniently ignores the value ``yield``ed *to* it. Is there any practical reason why you want to dig into this obscure generator nesting?

Comment: "There is only a single next call of each letter's _data_yielder. Why do you expect to see the other results of each _data_yielder?"

This instantly solved my problem! Thank you so so much!

Comment: Yeah, actually. The issue is that I've got a giant set of files I want to read over. Each entry in those files is a list of lists from which I want to iterate over. I have the "send" in there because it is tracking some variables

Comment: It's a little hard to explain (the example really is just that - an easy way to try and explain the error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: iterate over the nested. Look at

```
def _data_yielder(v, iter_to):
    for i in range(iter_to):
        bla = yield (v, i)
        print(f"Result received from send: {bla}")

def _get_data():
    """
    generator that iterates some expensive-to-open files
    """
    for i, v in enumerate(["A", "B", "C"]):
        offset = i + 2
        print(f"{v} should go up to {(v, offset-1)}")
        for (a, b) in _data_yielder(v, offset):
             yield (a, b)
        
def _reset():
    resetted_generator = _get_data()
    initial_value = next(resetted_generator)
    return initial_value, resetted_generator

count = 0
iter_data, data_generator_process = _reset()
print(f"\toutput value: {iter_data}")   
while True:
    try:
        iter_data = data_generator_process.send(f"test_{count}")
        count += 1
        print(f"\toutput value: {iter_data}")
    except StopIteration as e:
        print(e)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: I think you want to check out [``yield from``](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions). It basically means you can replace the loop-and-yield with ``yield from _data_yielder(v, offset)``.